# print another page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have two functions to print `element` and print `page`

```
function printPage(page,redirect,dontPrint=false)
{
    if($('.printThis').length == 0)
    {
        $('body').append('<div class="printThis hide"></div>');
    }
    $('.printThis').load(page,function(){
        printContent($('.printThis'),redirect,dontPrint);
        $('.printThis').remove();
    });
}

function printContent(div_id,redirect,dontPrint=false)
{
    var DocumentContainer = div_id.html();
    var html = '<html><head>'+
                   '<link href="'+tmpl+'assets/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'+
                   '</head><body style="background:#ffffff;">'+
                   DocumentContainer+
                   '</body></html>';
    var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow",
    "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
    WindowObject.document.write(html);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    setTimeout( function() {
        if(!dontPrint)
        {
            WindowObject.print();
            WindowObject.close();
        }
        if(redirect)
        window.location.assign(redirect);
    }, 50 );
}
```

form any page I put a button with on click function to print a page

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="printPage('/myproject/prints/bill/sales/5','')">Print Bill</button>
```

when user click the button for the `first time` it pop up a `blank page` !!!!
any time he clicks the button again it works fine

can you help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, you need to add this to the HTML code to print:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

This will start the print process as soon as the content is all loaded and rendered. No more timeouts!

---

Outside the scope of your answer:

**DO NOT** use popup windows (the line that says `window.open`). Plenty of people block those (I deeply thank to those who invented popup blockers) and it may not even work at all on some devices.

What you can do is create an `<iframe>` and dump contents to it.

Sorta like this:

```
<a href="/myproject/prints/bill/sales/5" target="print" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Print Bill</button>
<iframe id="print" name="print" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

When you click the link, it will open the page inside the  `<iframe>`. Since you are generating the output of the `<iframe>`, you can add the refered javascript code to the output.

This will save you a ton of work and keep as compatible as possible. Not to mention easy!

Answer (score -1):

Ok , I found my problem

it was the time to my page fully load so I increase the delay to 700 it works fine
thank you

Comment: Why like that? You can just add `<script>window.onload = function(){window.print()}</script>` to your iframe and it works.

Comment: Avoid using timeouts like this: Users have all different types of connections. Use an `onload` function to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: how to use `onload` function with `.load` , I am calling another page? and `no iframe`